# Documentação de sistema em conversão

Tags: c#, delphi, testes, documentação, scrum

Estou em processo de conversão de um sistema em Delphi para C# utilizando a metodologia SCRUM, até então não existe documentação deste sistema.

Então gostaria de saber o que indicam, não preciso de uma documentação muito técnica como diagramas e etc. A minha preocupação maior é em passar o sistema para equipe de teste sem que saibam o que terá de testar.

Alguma ideia, sugestão, exemplo?

Comment: Senta e chora..

Comment: "Sem que saibam o que terá de testar"? Sério mesmo? Qual é a razão de testar então? Outra coisa: vc vai fazer documentação (qualquer que seja) porque ela é necessária pra você (de forma clara), ou só porque alguém te disse que ela é necessária? Conversão de código geralmente não requer o mesmo nível de documentação que um projeto em andamento do zero. Alguma coisa tá errada em um nível mais profundo ai. Vou votar pra suspender porque hoje a pergunta parece meramente pedir por opiniões gerais. Melhore-a que eu voto para reabrir. :)

Comment: Meu caro @LuizVieira, quando disse "sem que saibam o que testar", quis dizer que, vamos converter o sistema e eles vão ter que "imaginar" o que testar, não vão ter nenhum roteiro e muito menos cenários de teste. A razão de testar é para garantir que o sistema "funcione" pelo menos da forma que era antes.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi Marcos. Mas eu acredito que se vc deixar para os testadores "imaginarem" o que testar, há muitas chances dos testes não serem suficientemente completos e deixarem passar coisas importantes. De todas as formas eu tenho a impressão de que esse não é o ponto central da sua dúvida. Ainda assim, qualquer coisa que alguém te indicar pode ser válida, e a pergunta fica simplesmente muito ampla. Este site não é um fórum. (Se não fez ainda, por favor leia a [help] e principalmente [ask]).

Comment: Por estar trabalhando com SCRUM e se tratar de uma metodologia ágil, eu como desenvolvedor não posso me estender elaborando diagramas ou mesmo um plano de teste. O que gostaria de saber se existe algum outro tipo de documentação, ou minha saída seria uma descrição comum sem seguir protocolos(outra metodologia de documentação).

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Se você está usando SCRUM então você já deve ter estórias de usuario na sua sprint, e cada estória possui os critérios de aceite (que geralmente são os que os testadores devem testar) e uma das razões de existir uma documentação, é dizer para quem vai criar a funcionalidade, como ela deve ser, e o que ela deve esperar de entrada e o que fornecer de saída. Êscrever documentação póstuma gera pouco valor, então imagine que a documentação é aquilo que será necessário para se conseguir resolver a história

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onde trabalho também possuem um sistema em Delphi que esta em constante migração para .NET. Não utilizam SCRUM mas possui a mesma situação de ter a área de testes para validar estas migrações.

O que fazem aqui é ter uma equipe responsável por elaborar Planos de Teste para que a equipe de testes tenha um "script" de todo o fluxo para testar a implementação que é liberada. Basicamente um passo a passo do que o cara precisa testar e do que o sistema precisa fazer.

Não sei se é o melhor caminho mas é o que utilizam aqui.

Comment: É uma boa @Vitor Ferreira, mas a empresa onde trabalho não uma equipe responsável para elaborar os planos de teste, ou seja, vai do desenvolvimento direto para teste. No caso os próprios desenvolvedores teriam essa tarefa. Obrigado pela sugestão!